# When I embed videos on my website what would be the referring IP?

Tags: html, ip

When I embed videos on my website what would be the referring IP?

My server or the clients machine?

Comment: I think that client machine.

Answer (score 0):

Definition According to magestic.com, the planet's largest Link Index database (https://majestic.com/support/glossary#RefIPs):

Referring IP's
    Many domains ( websites ) can be hosted on one IP address. A Referring IP refers to an IP which may host one or more websites, that may contain one or more links to a given target URL or Domain.